# CSS Responsive on bad resolutions

Tags: html, css

Trying to experiment with a responsive design. But using a bad resolution screen isn't helping. On my main screen it looks fine, they are all in line and if I shrink the browser the elements shrink into the min and max size.

On my main screen (1366 x 768) the segment looks like this:

[image]

However on another resolution (1280 x 720) it distorts:

[image]

Here is my CSS:

//Thumbnails

```
#menu {
    text-align: center; 


    }


.fader {
    /* Giving equal sizes to each element */
    //width:    250px;
    //height:   375px;
    //width:    33%;
    //height:   55%;
    max-width:    250px;
    max-height:   375px;
    min-width:    125px;
    min-height:   188px;  

    /* Positioning elements in lines */
    display:  inline-block;

    /* This is necessary for position:absolute to work as desired */
    position: relative;

    /* Preventing zoomed images to grow outside their elements */
    overflow: hidden; }


    .fader img {
        /* Stretching the images to fill whole elements */
        width:       100%;
        height:      100%;

        /* Preventing blank space below the image */
        line-height: 0;

        /* A one-second transition was to disturbing for me */
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -moz-transition:    all 0.3s ease;
        -o-transition:      all 0.3s ease;
        -ms-transition:     all 0.3s ease;
        transition:         all 0.3s ease; }

        .fader img:hover {
            /* Making images appear bigger and transparent on mouseover */
            opacity: 0.5;
            width:   120%;
            height:  120%; }

    .fader .text {
        /* Placing text behind images */
        z-index: -10;     

        /* Positioning text top-left conrner in the middle of elements */
        position: absolute;
        top:      50%;
        left:     50%; }

        .fader .text p {
            /* Positioning text contents 50% left and top relative
               to text container's top left corner */
            margin-top:  -50%; 
            margin-left: -50%;
            }
```

I am trying to make it so that no matter what resolution the third image doesn't drop down to another line. It should just shrink
Thank you for reading.

Comment: well, it would be better you give the sizes in percentages, this way it will accomodate appropriately on any resolution

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Are they supposed to shrink to the full width of the screen or do you want them to still align next to eachother and have a horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so the second resolution doesn't drop the element down on resize but instead it just shrinks.

Comment: @BradlySpicer  can you us your complete demo link we want to see that than we will be able to tell you the exact answer.....

Comment: http://profiledt.co.uk/tempmoodle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

**HTML**

```
<body>
     <div class="wrapper">  
        <div class="first">
            <img src="img/CourseExample1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="second">
            <img src="img/CourseExample2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="third">
            <img src="img/CourseExample3.png">
        </div>
     </div> 
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper{
    margin:0px auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.first{
    width:33%;
    float: left;
}

.second{
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}

.third{
    width:33%;
    float:left
}

.wrapper img{
width:95%;
}
```

Comment: I fixed it previously by adding some floats etc. But this works too ^^